# Python: list index out of range while iterating over a list [using del]

Tags: python-2.7, list, del

I have encountered the following problem when trying to iterate over this list. There is one argument deleted in the list but the stop of the iteration is the same. I have tried to add a `n-1` at the end of the code but that didn't make any difference.

I'm still a newbie so any explanation or help will be truly appreciated.

```
string_intrare = [['Gheorghe', 'Gita', '8', '7', '5.5', '10'],
['Vuia', 'Vasile', '4', '10', '10', '10'],
['Andreescu', 'Andra', '9', '10', '9', '10'],
['Elenescu', 'Elena', '5', '5', '5', '5']]
n = 4


for i in range(0,n):
    if (float(string_intrare[i][2]) < 5) or (float(string_intrare[i][3]) < 5) or (float(string_intrare[i][4]) < 5) or (float(string_intrare[i][5]) < 5):
        del string_intrare[i]
        print('List ' + str(i) + ' has been removed remove' + ' ===== Grade lower than 5')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\note_bacalaureat.py", line 16, in <module>
    if (float(string_intrare[i][2]) < 5) or (float(string_intrare[i][3]) < 5) or (float(string_intrare[i][4]) < 5) or (float(string_intrare[i][5]) < 5):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because in case the 'if' condition evaluates to true one of the list items gets deleted and the size of the list is now reduced but n is still the same and the for loop continues to iterate n times.

One possible way to make it work is this :

```
string_intrare = [['Gheorghe', 'Gita', '8', '7', '5.5', '10'],['Vuia', 'Vasile', '4', '10', '10', '10'],['Andreescu', 'Andra', '9', '10', '9', '10'],['Elenescu', 'Elena', '5', '5', '5', '5']]
n = 4


for i in string_intrare:
    if (float(i[2]) < 5) or (float(i[3]) < 5) or (float(i[4]) < 5) or (float(i[5]) < 5):
        print('List ' ,i , ' has been removed remove' , ' ===== Grade lower than 5')
        string_intrare.remove(i)
```

Comment: I have understood that but I m kind of stuck in trying to solve this

Comment: I have edited the answer and added a alternative working code

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I come closer to the solving of the problem. This one doesn't delete the list element though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. 'del' removes item by index so that would not work. 'remove' on the other hand removes item from list by value. The edited solution is now working.

Comment: If you want to use 'del' only you can do it as follows - del string_intrare[string_intrare.index(i)]